# WCF Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved, error converting to HTTPS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, wcf

im having issues with this WCF webservice . I was trying to make it run in HTTPS, in HTTP was running normally.
Im getting this error:

```
https://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WebServiceOppLink/Service1/mex Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WebServiceOppLink/Service1/mex'. An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WebServiceOppLink/Service1/mex. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote hostHTTP GET Error URI: https://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WebServiceOppLink/Service1/mex There was an error downloading 'https://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WebServiceOppLink/Service1/mex'. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

This problem appeared after i changed the protocols to HTTPS

And this is my 
App.Config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" />

  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseConnection" connectionString="Data Source=testserver2\\maximizer;Initial Catalog=financial;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=loiranoia" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>

      <service name="WebServiceOppLink.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior" >
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "https://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WebServiceOppLink/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!--
        <endpoint address="" 
        binding="wsHttpBinding" 
        contract="WebServiceOppLink.IService1">
         </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" 
        binding="mexHttpBinding" 
        contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        !-->
        <endpoint address=""
                    binding="basicHttpBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
                    contract="WebServiceOppLink.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
          <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
            <defaultPorts>
              <!-- Use your own port numbers -->
              <add scheme="http" port="80" />
              <add scheme="https" port="443" />
            </defaultPorts>
          </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Looks like its trying to use HTTP MEX to an HTTPS URL. but that its just a guess..
Could you guys help me on this one please?
cheers
W

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: i edited with the error.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
```

inside `system.serviceModel`

Comment: Nope, same error.

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://localhost:4578/Design_Time_Addresses/WebServiceOppLink/Service1/mex'. An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://localhost:4578/Design_Time_Addresses/WebServiceOppLink/Service1/mex. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.

Answer (score 0):

THere was 2 problems i solved my self,
1st the connection string was wrong

```
"Data Source=testserver2\\maximizer
```

It had  2 "\" 
secondly, The the Visual Studio cannot trust the self-certificate but running on a computer with a valid certificate it works.

i've got no time to lose trying to fix visual studio.

thanks any ways

cheers